# Верный порядок слов в «Щас так это называют»

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, порядок-слов

Какое из этих предложений правильней построено с точки зрения русского языка:
1. «Щас так это называют»;
2. «Щас это так называют»?

Comment: "С точки русского языка" слово "щас" не существует.

Comment: Если это цитата, то хотелось бы узнать автора. Если слова взяты из головы, то непонятно к чему здесь коверкать одно из них?

Comment: Хорошо. Пусть будет «сейчас».

Comment: @М_Г кажется, вы слишком строги ) все-таки язык не ограничивается книжной речью, ведь так?

Comment: оно конеЧно же существует в разговорной речи, да еСЧё как

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

При прямом порядке слов члены предложения обычно располагаются так:

-в повествовательных предложениях за подлежащим следует сказуемое: Учительница проверяла наши контрольные работы.

-приглагольное дополнение следует за определяемым словом: Учительница проверяла наши контрольные работы.

-согласованное определение ставится перед определяемым словом: Учительница проверяла наши контрольные работы.

-несогласованное определение стоит после определяемого слова: Она купила платье в горошек.

-обстоятельства могут занимать различное положении в предложении: Вчера он пришёл домой поздно. Мы поедем завтра в деревню.

Актуальное членение предложения предполагает смысловое ударение на реме, т.е. на последней части, на сказуемом.

*«Сейчас так это называют»* Ударение по смыслу явно должно быть на слове ТАК, но при таком расположении ударение падает на сказуемое *называют*. *Сейчас* - детерминант, обстоятельство, относящееся ко всему предложению, а не только к сказуемому. *Это* - тема. *Называют* - рема.

Чтобы ударение падало на ТАК, нужно перенести его во вторую часть предложения: *Сейчас это называют так.*

Или *Сейчас это так называют*

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения ритмики речи благозвучнее вариант 2, с точки зрения синтаксиса в варианте 1 смысловое ударение тяготеет к слову "называют", а в варианте 2 - к слову "так". Для выделения "так" в варианте 1 нужно приложить большее усилие.

Answer (score 0):

Дело **не в благозвучности и не в усилии при произношении**.

При перестановке слова "так" меняется актуальное членение предложения, что соответствует разным **оттенкам смысла** и используется **в разных ситуациях;**

1) Сейчас это //**тАк называют**. Местоимение "так" + глагол.

Пример: Только одни это //тАк называют, а другие иначе.

2) Сейчас **тАк это**// называют. Местоимение "так" + "это".

Пример: Сейчас тАк это //назывАют, а раньше называли по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Мое понимание:

1. *Сейчас так это называют*. Произносим: "Сейчас так **это** называют". Смысл: сейчас так (этим словом) называют **это**, а раньше этим словом называли что-то другое.
2. *Сейчас это так называют*. Произносим: "Сейчас это **так** называют". Смысл: сейчас это называют так, а раньше называли по-другому.

Comment: Сейчас тАк это называют. Или: Сейчас так Это называют. В этом предложении структура позволяет  без проблем  выделить ударением ЛЮБОЕ из этих слов. В реальности  же это будет зависеть от контекста, потому что смысл разный.

Comment: Все возможно, но чтобы произнести "Сейчас тАк это называют" нужно сделать над собой усилие, "сломать" фразу, нарушить естественную музыку языка. Звучит как скороговорка "Из-под топота копыт".

Comment: То, что вы называете ломкой, лежит в основе логического ударения. Предложение (даже простое) делится на фразы, и  нормой является ударение в конце фразы, но тогда конечное слово  не выделяется из общего текста,. Поэтому для логического выделения ударение переносится  в другое место (в начало или середину фразы). Есть известный пример на эту тему: Артамоновы жИли //ни с кем не знакОмясь. Это обычная интонация. У Горького: ЖИли Артамоновы // ни с кем не знакОмясь. Ударение на тех же словах, но при этом смещенное ударение логически выделяет первое слово. Такая вот полезная "ломка".

Comment: Кстати, в Нацкорпусе есть несколько примеров на эту тему,  и там используются оба варианта в предложениях разной структуры. Но если простое предложение состоит из четырех коротких слов, ударения без особых усилий можно ставить в любом месте, и при этом будет выражен разный смысл.